# fatal error C1189: #error : core.hpp header must be compiled as C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, opencv

I am building a C application that uses OpenCV.

when compiling, I get the following error:

```
fatal error C1189: #error :  core.hpp header must be compiled as C++
```

I did not find how to resolve this error.

How to use OpenCV from a C project?

Comment: Compiler is telling you that you cannot compile [tag:c++] source with [tag:c] compiler..

Comment: ... But OpenCV has pure C bindings. So you need to adjust your build process to use *those*.

Comment: How to change it to c++ compiler using visual studio, I tried but I cannot.

Comment: You have to build your OpenCV source in C  , what you are using is compiled in C++ and you are using in C

Comment: I'm not a VS expert but [this is the first googled link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270930(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the required file.
2. Launch its properties window
3. Goto C/C++ -> Advanced, and change **Compile as**  to **Compile as C++ Code (/TP)**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how much helpful will this be, but recently I faced with similar issue trying to compile the 'darknet' open source tool. The source includes a header files from OpenCV but needs to be compiled with C compiler and not with C++.

The codes were using the following headers and I have just changed the header names:
instead of:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

use the following:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
```

Comment: Yes, I did.  But I am using only CPU version (not GPU enabled).

Comment: Did you succeed to call the code of Darknet from a C++ file?

Comment: No, I didn't tried yet to use it in another program, I just compiled it and run through command line in terminal. But I don't think that if it works from command line then it will not work from C++ code. If you want you can send me your code, I may try it on my machine and let you know if same issue will arise.